# How to transfer some selected row from one Dataset to another in c#

Tags: c#

I have two dataset

```
DataSet dsvoucherget = new DataSet();
dsvoucherget = queries.getDetails(sqlVoucherget);
```

and

```
DataSet dsbalamount = new DataSet();
```

what I want to do is:

```
dsbalamount.Tables.Add(dsvoucherget.Tables[0].Select("RegnNo=EM01224").CopyToDataTable());
```

but I'm not able to do so please help

Comment: What do you mean "not able to do so"? What error do you get? Why are you using DataSet in the first place instead of strongly typed objects?

Comment: it is showing me The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: You should state that in your question. And you should show a representative summary of the contents of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = dsvoucherget.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["RegnNo"].ToString() == "EMO1224");

if (result.Any())
{
    DataTable tbl = result.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

You could use LINQ. You need `System.Linq` reference. If you want you can add the `DataTable` to `DataSet` after that.

Comment: all time value is false and showing warning possible unintended reference comparison; to get   a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Comment: @RahulChoudhary  
x["RegnNo"].ToString() write it like this.

Comment: one more question please if i have to add one more condition Month="Jan" then

Comment: @RahulChoudhary `dsvoucherget.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["RegnNo"].ToString() == "EMO1224" && x["Month"].ToString() == "Jan");`

Comment: and how to do the same thing in distinct[Month] format

Comment: @RahulChoudhary I don't understand you and please ask one question per post. If you have another question create a new post someone will answer you.

Comment: please tell me this time my question limit for today is over i want distinct month from dataset with regno="EM001234"

Comment: There is method Distinct() you can use it.